# MS-Graph AND sendmail with attachments Fails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
await graphClient.Users[sender].SendMail(message, saveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync();
```

I get error "SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
even when the size is less than 33MB
What is the limit?
Can it send emails with attachments at all?

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, [sendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) takes attachments that are upto 3MB - See [Example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-3). If the file is greater than 3MB, you need to upload the attachment using upload session. See [Attach large files to Outlook messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http)